# git command auto complete on tab not working in sub directories on mac

Tags: git, macos

```
$ git co <tabbing not suggesting commands like commit etc.. >
```

In root folder its working but not in sub directories

Comment: Your `.git` folder exists in the same folder where you are executing commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks

> Auto-Completion
>   If you use the Bash shell, Git comes with a nice auto-completion script you can enable. Download it directly from the Git source code at https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash . Copy this file to your home directory, and add this to your .bashrc file:

```
source ~/git-completion.bash
```

> If you want to set up Git to automatically have Bash shell completion for all users, copy this script to the /opt/local/etc/bash_completion.d directory on Mac systems or to the /etc/bash_completion.d/ directory on Linux systems. This is a directory of scripts that Bash will automatically load to provide shell completions.

Comment: For me it worked by adding "source ~/git-completion.bash" in .bash_profile

Comment: `test -f ~/git-completion.bash && . $_` will only run file if it exists. [Source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55886)

Answer (score 2):

### MAC zsh (12.4)

Put this Text into .zshrc
then execute it.

at the prompt % type:

```
> echo 'autoload -Uz compinit && compinit' >> ~/.zshrc
> source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve `git auto-complete`, I feel below steps are simple & helped me.

**Step 1**: Create file(`~/.git-completion.bash`) in mac machine and add content from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

```
> vi ~/.git-completion.bash
> copy-paste the content from linked shared above link
> Save the changes ( Press 'esc' button then press ':' then 'wq' then 'enter')
```

or with simple curl command

```
> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash -o ~/.git-completion.bash
```

**Step 2**: Link file `~/.git-completion.bash` with `~/.bash_profile`

```
> vi ~/.bash_profile
> add following code in ~/.bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  . ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
> Save the changes ( Press 'esc' button then press ':' then 'wq' then 'enter')
```

**Step 3**: Execute the newly added git-completion commands

```
> ~/. bash_profile
```

**Step 4**: Now you will be able to see git auto completion, just type `git br` and press `tab` now you should able to get completed command `git branch` or list of options to complete.

Reference -
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55875/git-auto-complete-for-branches-at-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks for sharing the reference as well. Very helpful.